# Read a single PDF page from server

Tags: php, pdf, embed

I need to embed PDF pages selectively, from a massive PDF of > 1000 pages (which, in turn, happens to be a 1000-slides powerpoint saved to PDF)

I am currently able, using Ghostscript, to extract a single page to a JPG and send it to the client.

Is there a way (preferably using PHP) to read a single page from the PDF and output as if it was a whole PDF for client side EMBED/OBJECT embedding?

- The purpose is to avoid rasterization, and just output a PDF page... as a PDF, hence retaining features such as the user being able to select text, vector-based elements not losing detail when magnified, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a jpg image, you can use [ImageMagic](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to convert it to pdf as following:

```
$img = new Imagick('path/to/image.jpg');
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$success = $img->writeImage('path/to/document.pdf');
```

It uses Ghostscript behind the scene, but you already have it installed, so it shouldn't be a problem.

**EDIT:**

With [php-pdftk](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk):

```
$pdf = new Pdf('/path/to.pdf');
if (!$pdf->cat(1)->saveAs('/path/to/page1.pdf')) {
    $error = $pdf->getError();
}
```

Comment: Sorry I think I had to be clearer: this, in fact, defeats the purpose - which is to avoid rasterization. I would like to output the PDF page /as pdf/, retaining all the features of a PDF

Comment: Works for me. Thanks